# Ajuda com select

Tags: sql, postgresql, query

Estou utilizando o comando `select` abaixo:

```
select
f.no_equipe,
h.no_pessoa_fisica,
a.no_cidadao,
d.dt_ficha
from
tb_cds_cad_individual a,
tb_cds_atend_individual b,
rl_cds_atend_individual_ciap c,
tb_cds_ficha_atend_individual d,
tb_equipe f,
tb_cds_prof g,
tb_pessoa_fisica h
where f.nu_ine = g.nu_ine
and g.nu_cns = h.nu_cns
and d.co_cds_prof = g.co_seq_cds_prof
and a.nu_cns_cidadao = b.nu_cartao_sus
and b.co_seq_cds_atend_individual = c.co_cds_atend_individual
and b.co_cds_ficha_atend_individual = d.co_seq_cds_ficha_atend_indivdl
and c.co_ciap = 727
and d.dt_ficha >= '2017-08-01'
and d.dt_ficha <= '2017-08-30'
```

Nesse código ele me retorna 4 campos: nome da equipe, nome do profissional, nome do cidadão e data da ficha.

Meu problema é na linha `and a.nu_cns_cidadao = b.nu_cartao_sus` onde ele só mostra a linha se o número do cartão do sus for igual ao número registrado em outra tabela.

Quero alterar o código para que, mesmo que a condição `and a.nu_cns_cidadao = b.nu_cartao_sus` não seja verdadeira, ele liste o resultado e no lugar no nome do cidadão `a.no_cidadao` apareça algo, tipo "SEM NOME".

Espero que tenham entendido.

Comment: Acredito que a resposta do @Sorack é a mais adequada ao seu caso :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize o `LEFT JOIN` em conjunto com a cláusula `CASE`:

```
    SELECT f.no_equipe,
       h.no_pessoa_fisica,
       CASE
         WHEN a.no_cidadao IS NULL THEN 'GESTANTE NAO CADASTRADA'
         ELSE a.no_cidadao
       END AS no_cidadao,
       d.dt_ficha
  FROM 
       tb_cds_atend_individual b 
       LEFT JOIN tb_cds_cad_individual a ON a.nu_cns_cidadao = b.nu_cartao_sus
       LEFT JOIN rl_cds_atend_individual_ciap c ON b.co_seq_cds_atend_individual = c.co_cds_atend_individual
       LEFT JOIN tb_cds_ficha_atend_individual d ON b.co_cds_ficha_atend_individual = d.co_seq_cds_ficha_atend_indivdl
       LEFT JOIN tb_cds_prof g ON d.co_cds_prof = g.co_seq_cds_prof
       LEFT JOIN tb_equipe f ON f.nu_ine = g.nu_ine
       LEFT JOIN tb_pessoa_fisica h ON g.nu_cns = h.nu_cns
 WHERE c.co_ciap = 727
 AND d.dt_ficha >= '2017-08-01'
 AND d.dt_ficha <= '2017-08-30'
```

Comment: a tabela `g` usa a `f` e a tabela `f` usa a `g`, não consegui ajustar isso :/

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo se uma está usando a outra as chaves, provavelmente, estão incorretas

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo o ideal é que use uma indentação e deixe as ligações mais legíveis com uso do join, isso facilitará sua vida :). O que o Sorack respondeu é correto, use o left join aliado ao case que será sucesso.

Comment: esse banco de dados é de um programa do ministério da saúde, estou pegando algumas informações dele pra gerar um relatório. ele tem 726 tabelas kkkkkk. mas estou tentando aqui.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o Case When ao selecionar ele e retira-lo do 'where', como abaixo:

```
select
    f.no_equipe,
    h.no_pessoa_fisica,
case when
     a.nu_cns_cidadao = b.nu_cartao_sus 
then a.nu_cns_cidadao
else 'SEM NOME' end,
     d.dt_ficha
from
   tb_cds_cad_individual a,
   tb_cds_atend_individual b,
   rl_cds_atend_individual_ciap c,
   tb_cds_ficha_atend_individual d,
   tb_equipe f,
   tb_cds_prof g,
   tb_pessoa_fisica h
where f.nu_ine = g.nu_ine
   and g.nu_cns = h.nu_cns
   and d.co_cds_prof = g.co_seq_cds_prof
   and b.co_seq_cds_atend_individual = c.co_cds_atend_individual
   and b.co_cds_ficha_atend_individual = d.co_seq_cds_ficha_atend_indivdl
   and c.co_ciap = 727
   and d.dt_ficha >= '2017-08-01'
   and d.dt_ficha <= '2017-08-30'
```

Não testei este código, mas acredito que resolva!

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso você pode fazer um `LEFT JOIN`, que faz a junção de resultados mantendo a linha caso a junção não seja positiva. E ao selecionar o campo usar o `COALESCE` para retornar um segundo valor caso o primeiro seja `NULL`. Exemplo:

```
select
    f.no_equipe,
    h.no_pessoa_fisica,
    COALESCE(a.no_cidadao, 'SEM NOME') AS no_cidadao,
    d.dt_ficha
from
    tb_cds_cad_individual a,
    rl_cds_atend_individual_ciap c,
    tb_cds_ficha_atend_individual d,
    tb_equipe f,
    tb_cds_prof g,
    tb_pessoa_fisica h
    LEFT JOIN tb_cds_atend_individual b ON a.nu_cns_cidadao = b.nu_cartao_sus
where
    f.nu_ine = g.nu_ine
    and g.nu_cns = h.nu_cns
    and d.co_cds_prof = g.co_seq_cds_prof
    and b.co_seq_cds_atend_individual = c.co_cds_atend_individual
    and b.co_cds_ficha_atend_individual = d.co_seq_cds_ficha_atend_indivdl
    and c.co_ciap = 727
    and d.dt_ficha >= '2017-08-01'
    and d.dt_ficha <= '2017-08-30';
```

Comment: Deu um erro na linha onde tem o join: `Hint: Há uma entrada para tabela "a", mas ela não pode ser referenciada desta parte da consulta.
Character: 345`